# using proper date and time stamp in script

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

In the script I am using I have

```
Sub Saveaspdfandsend()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
   Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + Format(Now, " yyyy-mm-dd hmmAM/PM") + ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = "csc.canada@philips.com"
        .Subject = xSht.Name + ".pdf"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
            '.Send
        End If
    End With
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

which will show 2018 04 06 245PM.
I tried to put a : between h and mm but it gives me an error when running the script.  I can use a space or a . but not a :
Is this not possible?

Comment: Where is your script running?  Excel?  Unix shell?  (unlikely) but please add a tag to your question to indicate what program / environment you are using.

Comment: Sorry.  It is in excel.

Comment: this is a VBA script macro I am running on a sales quote that saves the quote as a PDF and then attaches it in an email

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment, but I think a space between mm and AM will still do the trick. h:mm AM/PM. Also, I don't think you need that space between the opening " and yyyy.

Comment: the space between the " and yyyy is so that there is a space between the file name saved and date in that name.  I tried h:mm AM/PM and I get Run-time error '52": Bad file name or number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, file names cannot contain the character `:`. This is why there is a run-time error when you try to save the file.

You should also use a 24h format, instead of the AM/PM: `hhmm` seams safer to me.

Check [Format Function (Visual Basic for Applications)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

For proper Date & Time stamp your VB command line should be,

```
Format(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

or

```
Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Note: `DateTime.Now` returns a value of data type Date. Date variables display dates according to the short date & time format set on your system.

To display AM/PM, change your format string to this:

```
Format(TimeValue(Now), 'hh:mm AM/PM')
```